# Is there one code sample trigger copy constructor?

Tags: c++

```
string str=string("123");
string str="123";
```

is it same? are they both trigger copy constructor?
some one say they both trigger copy constructor. but the first one will omit the trigger, is it right?

Comment: It's up to the compiler whether to call the copy constructor or not. Any sensible one would not, though there is an option for making it call that, at least in GCC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if C++ defines a standard, however there is a way to figure out how your current compiler does it.

Run the following test on CTest below

```
TRACE("T1 Start\n");
CTest t1 = CTest("test");

TRACE("T2 Start\n");
CTest t2 = "test";
```

CTest Class:

TRACE can be replaced with printf or another debug tracing function.

```
class CTest
{
public:
    CTest(){
        TRACE("CTest()\n");
        m_pTest = NULL;
    }

    CTest(const char * pTest){
        TRACE("CTest(const char * pTest)\n");
        m_pTest = pTest;
    }

    CTest(CTest & test){
        TRACE("CTest(CTest & test)\n");
        m_pTest = test.m_pTest;
    }

    CTest & operator = (const CTest & test){
        TRACE("CTest & operator = (const CTest & test)\n");
        m_pTest = test.m_pTest;
        return *this;
    }

    CTest & operator = (const char * pTest){
        TRACE("CTest & operator = (const char * pTest)\n");
        m_pTest = pTest;
        return *this;
    }

    const char * m_pTest;
};
```

My current compiler (MSVC 2010) calls the constructor directly in both cases.

```
T1 Start
CTest(const char * pTest)
T2 Start
CTest(const char * pTest)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string str=string("123");
string str="123";
```

Both examples use the copy constructor.

Comment: Completely and utterly backwards.

Comment: Both of these examples use the overloaded constructor, not the copy constructor.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, In all normal cases, yes, though there is always that slight possibility, and the fact that one needs to be present. A very worthy mention, though, that by nearly everyone's standards, neither of these would call a copy constructor at all.